# What is a ZKRollup? And how does it work in scaling a DAPP?

Tags: contract-development, zero-knowledge, layer-2

I have tried looking into existing solutions such as [ZKSync](https://zksync.io/). I couldn't understand why you would rewrite your smart contracts in a different language - Zinc (as opposed to Solidity/Vyper).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the ZKP frameworks such as Zokrates, Circom, SnarkJS, gNARK etc. are designed for creating circuits, quadratic arithmetic programs and internal representations. Zinc is a fresh attempt to bring smart contracts to the ZKP frameworks with good guarantee for safety and security. It is constructed as a smart contract language optimized for ZKP circuits.